# Forward and reverse search in file after matching string with BASH

Tags: bash, file, loops, search, grep

I have a large file that consists of tests run sequentially. Each test has a test name and test data. I want filter out all tests that failed into a separate file. 
- The test names are enclosed in square brackets.
- The test data in the example below are the 4 lines in each test
- If a test fails it will have the keyword FAILED in it. 
Here is a simple example:

```
[CPU]
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
[Drives]
dddd
FAILED eeee
ffff
[Memory]
gggg
hhhh
iiii
[Power]
FAILED jjjj
FAILED kkkk
llll
[Graphics]
mmmm
nnnn
oooo
```

In this example 2 of the 5 tests failed so the output file would be:

```
[Drives]
dddd
FAILED eeee
ffff
[Power]
FAILED jjjj
FAILED kkkk
llll
```

Using BASH I can use grep to find the failed lines but I don't know how I can extract the full tests including the test names. I was thinking that after finding a match with grep I would use a do while loop and output each line to the file until it finds the [] above and below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `sed` command

```
sed ':a;N;/\[.*\]$/{/.*FAILED.*\n/{P;D};D;t};s/\n/-/g;$d;t a;' file_name | sed 's/-/\n/g'
```

**Explanation:**

```
N   -- Get the two line and store in the pattern space . 
t a -- continue the loop and append the line to the pattern space 
P   -- Print the first line in the pattern space .
D   -- Delete the first line in the pattern space .
```

**Execution way:**

`N` get the two line  and  `t loop` append  each line into the pattern space until the next block of header. After the header all the lines are considered as a single line by using substitution. Then some validation is performed like if `FAILED` pattern is found then print the until newline is found and delete it, else delete the line until newline, then continue the process. Finished all the process then substitute the every field with newline.

Comment: Kalanidhi do you mind explaining this to me here or privately as I would like to understand it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind is **very ugly** solution with temporary files:

```
split -l 4 --additional-suffix=.txt yourfile.txt tmpfile; grep -C 4 FAILED tmpfile*.txt
```

It is definitely not most efficient but could be useful especially if (as you wrote) you want to store failed output in separate files anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
gawk -v RS='\\[[^\\]]+\\]' /FAILED/ { printf "%s%s", p, $0 } { p = RT }' file
```

Output:

```
[Drives]
dddd
FAILED eeee
ffff
[Power]
FAILED jjjj
FAILED kkkk
llll
```

Comment: And a more conservative but longer approach: `gawk -v RS='\\[[^\\]]+\\]\n' 'NR > 1 && /FAILED/ { printf "%s%s", p, $0 } { p = RT }' file`. Not necessary if file format never goes different.

Comment: Thanks for that. Any chance you could explain it as I'm a noob and am struggling to understand it?